# Changing UIBarButtonItem colors

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

This is a pretty simple question and I really can't find the answer!

So okay, by default if I set the tintColor of a UIToolbar, the UIBarButtonItem's colors will be the same.

I only want to change the colors of my UIBarButtonItems and also change their text's colors.

Is there anybody out there having an idea on how to do so?

I really can't believe it is so complicated, really... changing an UIButton properties is so easy, I can't see why it's not the same for an UIBarButtonItem...

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you found the answer. Here's how I do it:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnGreen.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:0];
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[doneButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveDateEdit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[doneButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50, 30);
btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:doneButton];
[doneButton release];
```